# JMeter (java.net.SocketException)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I run my JMeter script and everytime after ~40 secounds i had this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3uVC.png)
my script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2MmT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help you without seeing the exception message and unfortunately your `???€?????` doesn't tell a lot to us.

1. Try switching to another terminal application like [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) or [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) which supports the output of the native localized symbols
2. Try [adding the language](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-a-language-for-windows-ccd853d3-9ecd-7da7-9ef0-72b4a055410a) in which exception is printed to Windows
3. Try [changing your Windows locale](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/how-to-change-system-locale-in-windows-10-the/d7826ef0-13cd-43ea-8e01-2846d813dfed) to the language in which the exception message is printed
4. Try changing `user.language`, `user.country` and `user.variant` properties in JMeter's [system.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)